# WebClient() UploadString() method is receiving the following error "The remote server returned an error: (599)" incase the passed string contain <>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webclient

I am facing this strange behavioure inside my asp.net mvc-4 web application. now i have the following `WebClient()` to upload a string to an external API:-

```
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mainresourceinfo);
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
                    {
                        string url = currentURL + "resources?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
                        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                        wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                        crudoutput = wc.UploadString(uri, "INPUT_DATA=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data));
                    }
```

and here is the json object i am sending (before url encoding it as per the API documentation which require to url encode the json):-

> INPUT_DATA="{\"operation\":{\"Details\":{\"RESOURCENAME\":\"test server
>   500123\",\"ACCOUNTNAME\":\"1\",\"RESOURCETYPE\":\"Windows\",\"PASSWORD\":\"<1234>\",\"NOTES\":null,\"Account
>   Type\":null,\"RESOURCEURL\":null,\"OWNERNAME\":\"admin\",\"RESOURCEGROUPNAME\":\"other
>   CUstomers\",\"DNSName\":\"-\",\"DEPARTMENT\":null,\"LOCATION\":null,\"RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD\":[{\"CUSTOMLABEL\":\"Asset
>   Tag\",\"CUSTOMVALUE\":\"H1007228\"}],\"ACCOUNTCUSTOMFIELD\":[{\"CUSTOMLABEL\":\"Account
>   Type\",\"CUSTOMVALUE\":\"domain\"}]}},\"createAccount\":{\"operation\":{\"Details\":{\"ACCOUNTLIST\":[]}}}}"

Now if my json object contain any value which have the following characters `<` or `>` the web client's UploadString method will get the following error:-

```
System.Net.WebException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (599).
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
       at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
       at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String data)
```

On the other hand, If i copy/paste the above json string inside the Firefox RESTClient debugger, and i run the call inside the RESTClient tool then operation will work fine...

so can anyone adivce why if i call the web service from my asp.net `WebClient` and the json object contain `<` or `>` i will get the following error `The remote server returned an error: (599)` ? while calling the web service using the same json string using FireFox's RESTClient debugger will work fine ?

Final note ,, If my json string does not contain any of these 2 characters `<` or `>` everything will be working fine.

**edit**

now when i use the RESTCleint tool to make a Post request to the 3rd party API ,, i can see the following response from the 3rd party API.. i got the following response header :-

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 15:29:37 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: PMP
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=B9CA7B68CD5706C3B82FE925B3AB3244; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000; includeSubdomains
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTP Status 500-599` means that the problem is within the server itself and not with the request.

If you can see the request headers of the one generated by `FireFox's RESTClient` then you can compare it with the one generated by `WebClient` just to help you isolate the issue.

If all else is still the same then you just found a bug on the web service.

Comment: so how i can know the request header inside the FireFox's RESTClient ?

Comment: I don't use FireFox's RESTClient but based on the product information it is a debugger for RESTful services and by the term 'debug' it is possible to see the request headers being sent by the add-on.

Comment: i try to find a way to know the request header but failed ...not sure what is going on ? beside this you said if i check the request header and it is the same as i am currently using inside the web client,,, then i might have find a bug on the web service,, But what kind of bug it could be,, that allow the FireFox RESTClient  to work well,, while my asp.net to fail ?

Comment: You better check the request headers first. I'm not sure but can't you open the developer tools in firefox while using RESTClient add-on? If I remember it correctly it is `F12` then on the Network tab you should see all HTTP requests details (header, body, parameters,cookies, timings, etc.).

Comment: now i changed the content type header from being "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to be ""application/json"" and i am able to call the external API correctly .. now sure what is going on ?

Comment: What's important to know are the request headers because it determines whether your request will be accepted by the API. If the 3rd party API have a documentation for developers then take a look into it and make sure you follow what is needed. Based on your result, the API does not accept `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` even though it should since you said that it is required to encode your json first. Lastly, the request format you're sending is not really JSON so might as well go for `text/html;charset=UTF-8` as your content-type.

Comment: Now inside the API documentation they mentioned to use "Content-Type: text/json" , but at the same time i faced some problems when i pass values such as 500%600 where this value got saved as 500`0 .. and when i send them an email regarding this problem they mentioned to url encode the json before sending it !! so now i am using the following 1) "wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;" 2) Content Type as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" 3) i am URL encoding my json string... now  tried sending many values which include UTF8 charecters , values such as "500%600" , "123%456"..

Comment: @ , "Ȁ ȁ Ȃ ȃ Ȅ"  and all of them where saved successfully,, so i am quite sure that using my appraoch should work well.. although i am not 100% sure why it worked . so i have UTF8 encoding for the WebClient + my content type header is  "application/json;charset=UTF-8" + i am sending the json in url encoded format ... not sure .. but according to my test now i am able to pass any characters !!1

Comment: To end this, you will not be able to know fully the reason unless you contact them and they explain it to you. It's a 3rd party API and you'll never know its structure unless it is open-source. Glad you made it work somehow. In my past project, we also made an API that accepts the exact format you're sending. More of a dictionary like json=*url encoded json* and the request content-type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for obvious reasons.